# Python function parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters

How to understand: twice call the function last_add(), but the id of the parameter is same.

```
def last_add(_list = []):
    _list.append('END')
    print(id(_list))

last_add()
last_add()
```

Comment: default parameters are stored in the function object itself

Comment: @Anthony Sottile Thank you!